# Technique to use to reduce the number of javascript lines to write

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

i am making a web page where i am having many graphs like the ones here

http://vz.comxa.com/v2/

I am using highcharts JavaScript charting library. To make one chart you write the code like shown here http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                        'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Exchange rate'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                data: data
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

and the html

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Since my charts are placed in modals,does it mean i must have the javascript for each chart in the page header. Due to the sheer number of charts involved,i reckon that's be a lot of JavaScript. What technique can i use to reduce the lines of javascript i will write?.

Comment: You can use the DRY tehnique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building multiple charts you can reuse same options. One way could be to use `Highcharts.merge` function to add new options to the common ones.

Demo with `Highcharts.merge` in use - 2 charts: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/

More complex option could be to create a custom series type with changed default options and optionally more features if required.

Demo - Sprakline: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/sparkline/